# Any dict-like mappable objects in Python that only show preview of contents when __repr__?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping, namedtuple

I'm looking for an object I can use to store largish dataframes and sklearn objects. Ideally I would like to store them as `pd.Series` because it has the behavior I'm looking for in that I can do the following:

- Get the object using some key:value pair
- Preview truncates large outputs
- Can reveal the keys inside easily

I can use `pd.Series` objects but don't know if the practice of storing complicated objects as values is frowned upon.

**Are there any other options I can use in the builtin library, `pandas`, `numpy`, `scipy`, or `scikit-learn`?**

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100)
y = list("abcde")*20
d = {"x":x, "y":y}
d
# {'x': array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]), 'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}

from collections import namedtuple
nt = namedtuple("Example", ["x","y"])
nt(x=x, y=y)
# Example(x=array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
#        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
#        34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
#        51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
#        68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
#        85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]), y=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

from sklearn.utils import Bunch
b = Bunch(x=x, y=y)
b
# {'x': array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]), 'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}

import pandas as pd
pd.Series({"x":x, "y":y})
# x    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 7...
# y    [a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d, e, a, b, c, d...
# dtype: object
```

Comment: If you're happy with Series, use them. What frowned upon is to use Series/DataFrame to store complex objects and then expect that operations should be simple and fast. If you're aware of the fact that you won't vectorize and can tolerate the potential larger overhead compare to dictionaries, I don't see an issue.

Comment: "I can use pd.Series objects but don't know if the practice of storing complicated objects as values is frowned upon." It is absolutely not. There is no problem, and that is perfectly normal